# Cannot log in or add items to cart in Magento after migrating to new server

Tags: magento

I have migrated a Magento site to another server (the same server the database was already hosted on) and I am no longer able to log in or add items to my cart.  I have found a few others who have posted about this type of problem but nothing seems to work for me.  I have disabled all caching, etc.  Ensured that sessions work.  Increased the session lifetime.  No errors are being logged anywhere.  If I enter wrong credentials I get an error.  But if I enter the correct information it just keeps returning me to the login page.  I have opened permissions completely.  Nothing makes any difference!  So aggravated.  Please help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't even realize that.  I found the answer to this issue so I will post it now.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  Well sort of.  I think there was a problem with the timezone (the server I moved to was an hour different from the other) but essentially I resolved the problem by increasing the values for two config items in core_config_data:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=86400 WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_lifetime';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=86400 WHERE path='admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime';
```

The first query fixed the shopping cart problem, the second the admin login problem.

Again I think there is a mitigating factor here as well, but this at least got me over the hump.